# How to convert this json array into list

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, arrays

My json Array:

```
 {"lstResult":[{"food_photo":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1........3,5],"food":"12","qty_uom":"Pcs","unit":null}]}
```

my C# class:

```
 public class lstresult
    {
    public photo[] lstResult{get;set;}
    }

public class photo
{
public byte[] food_photo{get;set;}
}
public class Food
{
    public photo[] food_photo { get; set; }
    public int food_qty { get; set; }
    public string qty_uom { get; set; }
    public string unitcost { get; set; }
}
```

My question:

> my json string contain a "food_photo" key how to convert this byte array into
>   image? or convert into list in asp.net
>   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class LstFooddtlResult
{
    public List<int> food_photo { get; set; }
    public string food { get; set; }
    public string qty_uom { get; set; }
    public string unitcost { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<LstFooddtlResult> lstResult { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Javascript Serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Here is some example code on using Javascript Serializer

```
string json = "[{Name:'John Simith',Age:35},{Name:'Pablo Perez',Age:34}]"; 

public class Person
{
   public int Age {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Person [] persons =  js.Deserialize<Person[]>(json);
```

Comment: :hai!i want to convert food_photo key to image in my json string....how to do that?

Comment: "or convert into list" is what you said... I tot it would be nice to introduce you to Javascript Serializer :)

Comment: ya i wanna convert into list but i fail in converting food_photo into list..it show null....when i run